# Custom module left tab menu in admin magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have tried to follow the tutorial to make the left menu on the link
[here](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/11/01/module-development-series-magento-admin-module-part3/) and working perfectly

examples I have two tabs, tab1 and tab2 each have a different form, but do not have two action buttons

how do I create action buttons that each different form of action?

Tab1
[image]
Tab2, when I switched to tab2, action button unchanged
[image]

Comment: Did you get any console error in your browser??

Comment: there is not error, it's working perfectly,
what i want is, when i switch from tab1 to tab2 the uri controller change also